# Are basic data types in C mutable or immutable by default?

Tags: c, variables, types

I've found many information about the mutability of data types in C#,java... But what about pure C.

for example, is `int` immutable in C by default?

For example, looking at the following code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a,b,c;
  b=0;
  c=0;
  a=b+c;
  b=1;
  c=2;

  printf("1st time %d\n",a);//gives out 0
  c=3;
  printf("2nd time %d",a);//gives out 0
  return 0;
}
```

The above code shows that an ordinary `int` is immutable, am I right?

Comment: Only data declared as **const** is immutable

Comment: Roger is correct in one sense, but it is possible to overwrite the memory location of even a `const int`.

Comment: @Shredderroy Not necessarily, that depends on the scope of the `const int`, and the system. In an embedded system with true read-only memory, `const` variables will get stored in flash/EEPROM. Then you can't overwrite them no matter how many ugly casts you do. But on the other hand, only file scope (globals/static) const variables gets placed in true read-only memory, because on an embedded system you may want the immutable feature as well. So it will always be possible to overwrite local const variables, as they are always stored in RAM.

Comment: @Shredderroy I am fairly confident that attempting to overwrite a `const` anything is UB (undefined behavior) in C.  I'll need to look it up - it's late.  Write may/may not work.  Example: `const` data memory is made read-only after program loading.  You can try to overwrite, but nothing changes.

Comment: @chux Yes, it is always undefined behavior. C11 6.7.3 `"If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined."`

Comment: @Lundin  I concur with most of what you say except about local `const` variables.  Also in embedded (PIC) with a Harvard architecture, local `const` variables, such as string constants are in read-only memory.

Comment: @chux That's probably because PICs have such tiny stacks and are unsuitable for C programming in general. I don't see what it has to do with the Harvard architecture.

Comment: @Lundin True - The Harvard architecture is not a big part of the answer as you questioned.  But HA does promote code and constant data in one space and non-constant data in another.  In doing so, generated code allows reading const data, but makes not provision to write.   BTW PICs of last couple years partition off a piece of RAM  - as much as you want.  Yet I recall - those old 8 deep stacks.  But a bit off topic.

Comment: @Lundin - Incidentally, recent PICs (eg. pic32mx and dspic24) have more than enough space for C programming, I've done some pretty sophisticated things with them.

Answer (score 5):

`[I]s int mutable in C?`

The short answer: yes it is!

If you are asking whether it is possible to mutate any memory location in C, the answer is yes.  (Sometimes with dangerous consequences!)  While it is possible to design a data structure that cannot be mutated directly through the API you have created for it, you *can* pretty much overwrite any memory location in pure C.

No wonder some love it, others don't.

**EDIT**

In reference to Roger's remark above:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const int n = 1;
    int *m = &n;
    *m = 10;
    printf ("%d\n", n); /* prints 10 */
    return 0;
}
```

So, yes, it is possible to overwrite the memory location of even `const int`s.

Comment: const is more of a hint to the programmer about as effective as a road sign, you do not need to follow the arrow :-)

Comment: No, C ain't as bad as you present it. Your code is misleading. The way you do this is a constraint violation and your compiler should have issued a diagnostic. To do that "properly" you'd have to cast the `const`ness away, after which C assumes you know what you are doing.

Comment: I agree.  And `gcc` does issue a warning, but programme compiles and runs anyway.  But already, if it is possible to cast the `const`ness away, then you have to agree the structure isn't so immutable after all.

Comment: @Shredderroy, no that doesn't say that it is immutable if you cast. It says that you told the compiler that you suppose you know what you are doing. The program might well crash on you if you execute it. You forced undefined behavior, so all bets are off.

Comment: I think undefined behavior that may or may not cause a segfault is enough to make it neither immutable nor mutable.  It's not defined, and therefore may be neither, because there are no guarantees.

In most cases, const should be immutable as far as the standard is concerned, and that's what is most important.  Talking about non-standard behavior, whether it works or not in any given situation, is pointless.

Comment: -Wall: `warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]`

Answer (score 5):

Ordinary `int` is mutable.  An entity that is (not merely claimed to be at some point, but "really is") `const` is not-mutable-in-theory and if the hardware and software cooperate, often not-mutable-in-fact as well.

Defining a variable using the `const` qualifier makes it "really" const:

```
const int c3 = 3;
void f(void) {
    const int c4 = 4;
    ...
}
```

With "tricky" code (casting away the const-ness) you can convince the system to write, or attempt to write, new values into `c3` and/or `c4`:

```
void f(void) {
    const int c4 = 4;
    int *p;

    p = (int *)&c3;
    *p = 99;
    printf("c3 is now %d\n", c3);
}
```

If you call `f()` you may, on some systems, find that c3 changes and becomes 99.  On other systems you may get a "segmentation fault" or other run-time error.

Change the references to use `c4` and the same things can happen—although in practice, few if any systems produce a run-time error.  However, you may observe something else entirely: instead of printing `c4 is now 99` you may get `c4 is now 4`.

This last can happen because the compiler is allowed to *assume* that, having made `c4` a `const int` with value 4, you, the programmer, never changed it.  That `*p = 99` must not have changed it (even if it did), so the call to `printf` can be replaced with a different call that just prints 4.

The same is generally true of references to `c3`: the compiler can *assume* that since you promised never to change it, you never actually did change it.  This can produce surprising results, such as: `p == &c3` being true, `c3` being 3, and `*p` being 99.  But a run-time error is pretty likely, because most modern compilers and OSes cooperate to stick `c3` into a read-only region.

When string literals produce arrays (which is most of the time), C has a quirk.  These arrays are not `const`-qualified, but the characters making up the array are read-only anyway (at least in principle, as with `const int c3 = 3;`).  Like `c3`, most modern systems manage to make them "really read-only".

(String literals do not produce arrays when they are used as initializers for objects of type `array of char`.  Compare:

```
char *ronly = "this string is read only";
char rwarray[] = "this string is read/write";
```

Here `ronly` is a pointer, not an array, so the string literal produces an array and `ronly` points to the first character of that array.  The underlying array *is* read-only, even though its type is `char [25]`.  But `rwarray` is an array, not a pointer, so the string literal fills it in—and sets its size to 26—and it is mutable.  You would have to write `const char roarray[] = ...` to make it immutable.  [Some like to spell the type `char const []`, with the const coming after the data-type.  These mean the same thing.])

Answer (score 3):

I think you are fundamentally misunderstanding what it means to be mutable or at the very least how procedural languages work. Here is your code with the values of a,b and c commented in:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) // Good practice to declare main with `(void)` instead of ()
{
  int a,b,c;                 // a,b, and c are garbage values (whatever was left in memory)
  b=0;                       // a == garbage, b == 0, c == garbage
  c=0;                       // a == garbage, b == 0, c == 0
  a=b+c;                     // a == 0, b == 0, c == 0
  b=1;                       // a == 0, b == 1, c == 0
  c=2;                       // a == 0, b == 1, c == 2

  printf("1st time %d\n",a);
  c=3;                       // a == 0, b == 0, c == 3 
  printf("2nd time %d",a);
  return 0;
}
```

Once `a` is assigned, it isn't magically updated because `c` and `b` change. That has nothing to do with mutability vs. immutability. In fact, by assigning b and c to 0 and then later reassigning them to 1 and 2 respectively, you demonstrated that `int`s (and all data types in C that are not declared `const` actually) are in fact mutable.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not an answer, I am not 'reputed' enough to comment or vote.

1. Lovely piece on C constness by @torek above (Also a reason for those online testers to not include such raw questions in their multiple choice questions).
2. As a beginner in javascript where the term 'mutable' means (I think) that you can add properties to it (using the 'prototype' object in javascript).

In any case, in the code piece you wrote in the question, the statement a=b+c; only changes the *value* of 'a' with the *values* of 'b' and 'c' at that point in the code block (which are both 0), with all 3 variables retaining their original addresses.  So any changes you make to the assigning variables after the statement will not affect the value of 'a'.  And in C, this fact doesn't make it 'immutable', which means the value cannot be changed.